# The support library of Emoji Compatibility can't use in Android Studio

Tags: android

I learned that Support library 26 supports use of emojis. But when I use the support library as follows:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:26.0.1"
```

I get this error:

[image]

and when I click `Install Repository and sync project` nothing happens. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add google repository like below in build.gradle file for your application to make it work:-

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Also check below url for more info:-

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html