# Android annotion (Nullable) not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not sure what is the last solution for android annotation, I implemented the latest API but still don't work
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgoOa.jpg)

here is my build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

any suggestions, I try several methods listed in stackoverflow but non of them works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023971/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-26-0-1

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations) you have to use this:

```
 dependencies { implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0' }
```

Also I've seen things such as `@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")` used in some of my personal code if that helps