# Exception, Error converting bytecode to dex, Exception parsing classes, Return code 1 for dex process

Tags: java, android, dex

**N.B. This Question Is not a match as I cant find any working solution.**

I have used almost every process to solve this but still facing same.

**First**: `multiDexEnabled true`

**Second**: `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

**Third**: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m` (in `Local.properties`)

**Fourth**: `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` (In `manifest.xml)`

**Fifth**: `Clean & Rebuild`

**Sixth**: `File` < `Invalidate cache & Restart`

If anyone is looking for solution, These may work for you. But for me none are working.

What should I do ? (I'm working on Digital wallet project).

Errors: 1:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
```

Error 2: `Error:1 error; aborting`

Error 3:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.intuition.paytmprogress"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
//        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

//    PayTm
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_V2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/paytm-checksum_2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar')

    //Freecharge
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
//    compile 'in.freecharge.checkout.android:freecharge-checkout-android-sdk:2.2@aar'
//    compile 'in.juspay:godel:0.6.12.1423'
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: Sure. give me 2 sec.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs Done..

Answer (score 0):

For your Application Multidex not required.

Don't use + operator in dependency version.

Try this new Config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.intuition.paytmprogress"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Remove the multiDex application from the manifest.

2) I can see some of the commented dependencies.

if you use those dependencies follow these instructions.

- Remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'` from it. Because support-v7 library includes v4 support library.
- Ensure your libraries using the same version of your support library. if you got a red line under your support library saying found multiple version of support library. you have to downgrade your support library version to match that.
- Add multidex only it exceeds single Dex.

Clean and Rebuild your project.

Comment: If I add external Jar files I can see same issues again. :(

Comment: Still getting Errors.........Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4-output C:\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\paytm-checksum_2.0_0927f64182307d227e049.jar C:\AndroidStudioProjects\app\libs\paytm-checksum_2.0.jar}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same the version for `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, and the `support library`. Hence, you need to use version 26. So, you need to change it something like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26 // need version 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3" // need version 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.intuition.paytmprogress"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    // Need version 26.
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'  
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Don't use **multidex** because you don't need it yet.

**-- UPDATED--**

FOr support version `26.1.0`, you need to add the google maven to your root build.gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Read more at [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0/)

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.3'  <--I'm getting Error This package is not available to download.

Comment: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: PARSE ERROR:
class name (com/paytm/pg/AppTest) does not match path (target/test-classes/com/paytm/pg/AppTest.class)
...while parsing target/test-classes/com/paytm/pg/AppTest.class
-----------------------------------------------------This is the error I am getting still.

Comment: That's is a different kind of error. You need to check `com/paytm/pg/AppTest` for the class.