# DUPLICATE ERROR: While generating signed APK for release in android

Tags: android, build.gradle, signed-apk

I'm trying to generate **SignedAPK** for deploying it in the **Play Store**, but I'm getting the following error. But while building as debug mode it works very fine.

**ERROR:**

Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManagerCompat$Api23FingerprintManagerCompatImpl$1.class
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.meru.parryreward"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
configurations {

    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'


    //  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-vector-drawable'


  }
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

}
```

I have tried almost everything suggested in SO but couldn't resolve this error. I'm a beginner Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete `android-support-v4.jar` in your libs folder.. delete it

than **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** your Project

> if this `android-support-v4.jar` file is not added in the `build.gradle` file. `gradle` includes it in the build anyway.

Comment: I removed that jar from my libs folder but now getting build errors on almost all the java files in the imports. @Nilesh

Comment: try to complie this lib `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'`

Comment: i found the library in the external libraries. but when i right clicked on it. i couldn't able to find compile option.

Comment: @RakeshPolo didn't get u

Comment: As you told me earlier i am trying to compile the lib but dont know how to do it.

Comment: add thet depedency in gardle than click build menu than click clear menu @RakeshPolo

Comment: @RakeshPolo try this compile this lib `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4::26.0.+'` and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.+`

Comment: @RakeshPolo remove aplha version

Comment: while adding the dependencies you told i am getting the following error.
`Error:Could not find support-v4-26.0.+.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1).
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/home/kumar/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1-26.0.+.jar

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have a conflicted support library version. You need to use the same support library version.

In your case, try using support-v4 library from maven instead of local jar:

```
dependencies {
  ...

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4::26.0.0-alpha1'

  ...

}
```

Try using the [recent support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) which is `26.1.0`. **Never** use alpha version in your release apk.

If your `build.gradle` only include all dependencies as your above answer, you don't need to enable multidex and set it as false with `multiDexEnabled false`. And also, try removing the following code in it:

```
configurations {

    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'


    //  all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-vector-drawable'


  }
```

Comment: if i remove the configurations and add new dependencies im getting following error. `Error:Could not find support-v4-26.0.+.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1).
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/home/kumar/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-26.0.0-alpha1-26.0.+.jar

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>`

Comment: You need to add the google maven. Please look at my answer about the maven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0/45876864#45876864

Comment: I did that too `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}`

Comment: In the SDK tools i have installed everything that comes under support repository. still error persists.

Comment: That's strange. Could you attach your **root** `build.gradle` in your question?

Comment: I have added it. Please check

Comment: add your maven to allProject: `allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
   maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}`