# Error:(34, 12) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android

when i use recycleview   this error found 
Error:(34, 12) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.0.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
compile'com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.0.0'  and compile'com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'  both i  try  but they all can't success. who can help me

this is gralde file: 
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exploapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile'com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.0.0'
}
```

other gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url"https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image: this is the content "D:\androidsdk\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `maven` block:

give space between `url` & `"https://maven.google.com"`

It should look like: `url "https://maven.google.com"`

Next,

1. Go to Android SDK from Android Stuido
2. Click `Show Package Details` on bottom right corner
3. Click Latest version of `Android SDK Build-Tools`, `Android SDK Platform-Tools` & `Android SDK Tools` (Look at attached screenshot)
4. Install `Android Support Repository` & `Google Repository` if you haven't
5. replace `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'`

with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

6. Replace `compile'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'`

with `compile'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`

7. Replace `compile'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'`

with `compile'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'`

8. Replace `compile'com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.0.0'`

with `compile'com.android.support:recycleview-v7:26.1.0'`

[image: Android SDK]