# Gradle DSL method not found:'compile' error(31, 0)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just added a design support in app/build.gradle file. when I synced the file, there was an error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thiis is my app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android{
       complieSdkVersion 26
       buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
       defaultConfig{
                 application "sun.example.test"
                 minSdkVersion  15
                 targetSdkVersion  26
                 versionCode  1
                 versionName "1.0"
                 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes{
            release{
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles  getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
       }
}

dependencies{
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
        exclude group" 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}'

}
```

Comment: what the hell is this line ?

`        compile 'com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}'
`

Comment: replace that line with com.android.support:design:26.0.0

Comment: just is compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'.

Comment: noway man the compileSDKVersrion should be matched  with the version of  supported lib

Comment: i replaced but it is still error

Comment: what should i do

Comment: Hmmm okay then try to add 
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
replace that line

Comment: if it is still not compiling then add the google maven repository 


  maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }


to project gradle

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: first, The project 'Test' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method(e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync projest.second, The project 'Test' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.open Gradle wrapper file.third, The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin.

Comment: is there any suggestion like download plugin ?

Comment: the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' in project gradle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0

Comment: didnt work@Basil Battikhi

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
        exclude group" 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
```

Pay attention to the `{}` and `group:`
Use:

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
```

Comment: didn't notice that :D