# Android Studio dependency resolution

Tags: android, dependencies, resolution

I downloaded Android Studio 3.0 and wanted to run my very first app (just using studio's default code with a blank activity).
But I keep getting the following errors.

First error message:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not 
resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
   Required by:
     project :app
       >Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 
     'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-
          v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
             > Could not GET 
     'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-
     v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
               > dl.google.com
```

Second error message:

```
    Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': 
    Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
    Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
     Required by:
       project :app
          > Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
             > Could not get resource 

      'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner/ 
       1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
          > Could not GET 
        'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/test/runner 
         /1.0.1/runner-1.0.1.pom'.
                   > dl.google.com
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0) and tell me how it goes.

Comment: I have already tried it. But no change. By the way I'm having this problem only on my laptop,which has 64 bits Windows. On the other hand, my desktop is a 32 bits Windows and I can run the same project on it  without any errors.