# Intellij IDEA Failed to resolve:com.android.support."......."

Tags: intellij-idea

i'm really interested in making android apps but android studio have a lot of problems to me so i got to the root Intellij IDEA and there is that error without an answer to it. Here is a photo that shows what is the error:
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvHlY.png)

Well when i click install  repository it doesn't download anything...Actually there were thee errors but one of them actually installed.

[EDIT]
I had a problem with the whole program, I had to reinstall it and after I got the same error install what it wanted from the link and everything worked just fine

Comment: where are you from?

Comment: why are you asking?

Comment: you may need proxy so that the repository would be downloaded. i think you have internet connection problem or something like that.

Comment: i have proxy and even one of the tree downloaded but the other dont want to. i tried to download the one who dont  want to before the one who did...still noting.

Comment: Can you build it from command line? Check that you have repositories defined in build.gradle file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45481709/2000323