# android studio appcompat v7:26

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with android studio.
I will create a new project (without changing the parameter, just the next one), then I encounter these problems.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project level `build.gradle` and add this after that sync

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> From version 26.0.0 of support libraries make sure that the
>   repositories section includes a maven section with the
>   "https://maven.google.com" endpoint.

[Read Document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

> For Gradle build tools plugin version 3.0.0, you can use google()
>   repository:

[Read Document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```