# Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android

I recently update my Android Studio to version 3.0.1 and I started a new project with a blank activity. As soon as the gradle sync starts(as soon as I open the project)I get a message in Event Log :

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
                Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
                Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar'.
                Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar'.
                Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/216.58.197.46] failed: Connection refused: connect
                Connection refused: connect
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3s 878ms)
```

I reinstalled the support repository from Android SDK manager and adding maven to the dependencies but so far have been unable to resolve the issue.

The build-gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {  
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level build-gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vishalbisht.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: share your **`Build-Gradle`** with question

Comment: post your app level `build.gradle` file

Comment: @Nilu hope this helps.

Comment: @VishalBisht for test case **`buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"`**

Comment: Your error says `Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/216.58.197.46] failed: Connection refused: connect` try syncing with stable Internet connection

Comment: @Firoz Memon the internet connection is stable

Comment: @VishalBisht your internet connection may be stable but it might be case that in your system this address is blocked.Try hitting "https://maven.google.com/" this url in your browser.

Comment: This seems odd, but in my case, trying Gradle Sync again after a minute or two, the error was gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue by commenting the following lines in app level build-gradle

```
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:3.0.1'
```

and then it started working not sure if this is an acceptable solution but as of know I can at least run and compile my code.

Also after the Android studio 3.1 update, I have not faced this issue.

Comment: Vishal, it works! Would you mind explaining why we need to comment out those 2 lines?Thanks.

Comment: @userIndulgeInDChord My understanding at that point was that these two libraries were not updated to be compatible with the improved build process for android version 3.0.1. which Version of Android studio did you face the issue on?

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
 android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vishalbisht.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

To

```
 android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vishalbisht.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And Use any one of this `google()` **or** maven `{ url "https://maven.google.com" }`

Read my Previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765358/6314513)

Comment: Does not do anything

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the solution would be as below

1. check target version in your app build.gradle

   **targetSdkVersion 30**
2. Go to SDK manager and check whether you have the same SDK which should 30 as the API level

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your Gradle and Gradle version plugin to the last version. and migrate your project to androidx.

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

and gradle.wrapper

```
#Mon Nov 04 15:09:35 IRST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted this in the build.gradle module and it worked.

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

as i was also using

```
google()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle module and remove the dependencies highlighted in the error log.
Most likely you have added and obsolete dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).