# Gradle android error

Tags: android

When i want to build my project, it's failed and there's error.
This is my gradle setting of my project.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ Install Repository and sync project
> Open File
> Show in Project Structure
>   dialog

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Add google() to dependency block in project Gradle it already not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0)