# Unable to Get Latest Google Play Services - Google API for Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My problem is simple but I am not able to resolve it.

I have updated latest version of Android Studio and my Android SDK Manager[Screen Shot Attached] says that I have latest version of Google Repository but actually I don't have the latest versions installed. I only have Google Play Services version **11.0.4** on my machine in Android SDK Folder but its not latest version, the latest version has reached to **11.8.0** mentioned [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

I have tried everything but I am not able to download the latest version and I need help please.

Please tell me how can I download the latest version of Google APIs for Android.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to download the latest google play service. Starting from 11.2.0, it is available through Google's Maven repository. Read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0/45876864#45876864

Comment: Actually I am developing in Unity so I need selective aar file is there any way to get aar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Google Play Services from the SDK Manager. It is recommended to use your gradle `build.xml` to get it from Google's maven repository. See [the setup guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

If you are developing on Unity there are many plugins you can use, just Google Search for "Google Play Services Unity".

Comment: Actually I am developing in Unity so I need selective aar files is there any way to get aar files?

Comment: A Quick google search for "Google Play services Unity" shows lots of plugins which should help you.