# Support Libraries must have same version specification Error GRADLE BUILD

Tags: android, build.gradle

[Error at line 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCBdQ.png)

[image]
I don't Know why it's giving me this error.
I checked all over internet but didn't get a good solution which can fix that.

Comment: use same version of compileSdkVersion and in your dependencies use same version

Comment: in your gradle you could see something like this "25.1.0" or something similar to that make sure all of your gradle file libraries have same versions like it

Comment: if you could post the gradle screenshot i could provide the correct answer

Comment: its same as of compileSdkVersion

Comment: @ADShots post your app.gradle file

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.gochat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: its the above part

Comment: just change "v4" to "v7" it will do the trick

Comment: Error:(24, 20) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v7:26.1.0
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/akshit/AndroidStudioProjects/GoChat/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: getting this error when i change it to 7

Comment: Add this in build.gradle(Project:projectname)

allprojects { repositories { jcenter() maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } } }

Add this in build.gradle(Project:projectname)
allprojects { repositories { jcenter() maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } } }
                                         Add this in build.gradle(Module:app)                    
dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' }

Comment: just refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0