# android studio failed to Could not resolve com.android.support:design:27.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Well, I met a problem about gradle sync today.
The problem is like this:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.android.support:design:27.1.0.

But I actually add the dependence in `app/build.gradle` dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
  ...
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
  ...
}
```

I didn't turn the gradle offline mode on. And it is connected to the Internet. But it seems didn't auto download the dependence. Also other dependencies like this

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

I can't solve it. Each answer is helpful. 
The detailed gradle properties is like this.

```
{
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lqs2.materialtest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45876864/4758255)

Comment: disable the `work offline` in grandle setting and  rebuild the project again. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Are your repositories correct? Please verify if:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

In your project's Build.Gradle (Note: the project's Build.Gradle, not the module's).

Comment: Yes, it has correct repositories. But the problem always occurred. Any dependency can't be resolved. I have ever turned on the Http proxy. But I have turned it off.

Comment: Ok. Why do you have "implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"? Are you trying to use libraries as files in your /libs directory?

Comment: It was auto generated. I tried to rebuild the project . I found that             ---------------Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:80 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused).

Comment: My guess was that there were conflicts between the *.jar files you had in your /libs folder and the ones you are importing from the repositories. You can't have the same libraries on both. Either use one approach or the other. But if it's not that, I am out of ideas. Maybe if you provide more info. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I reinstalled the gradle  and it works well now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the repositories appears to be important.  Try placing "google" before "jcenter"