# Gradle sync failed - Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7:26

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I use this code in my app/build.gradle.

```
  android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.avizhegroup.android.dsmmaps"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.1"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }



repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.zookey:universalpreferences:0.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bosphere.android-filelogger:filelogger:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    implementation files('libs/usbdriver.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/libs/rlmotgusbdriver.jar')
    implementation 'me.imid.swipebacklayout.lib:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}
```

I have a problem when syncing Gradle. these problems have occurred:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: design
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: transition
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-v4
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-media-compat
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: animated-vector-drawable
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-fragment
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-core-utils
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-core-ui
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-compat
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-annotations
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: runtime
>       Affected Modules: app
>       ERROR: Failed to resolve: common
>       Affected Modules: app

I uncheck variant in Experimental in preferences, change dependencies, change SDK version, change grade version and ... . this code works in windows, but in Mac doesn't.
I use constraint-layout and AndroidStudio3.3.2
How can I correct this?
Thanks

Comment: probably related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0/ ?

Comment: Try my answer and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567904/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-resolve-appcompat-v726/55568023#55568023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add google maven to your root `build.gradle` like below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()

    }
}
```

Comment: A few years later and this is the fix that I needed. Seems goofy, but I had added maven url statements, such as maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } to allprojects{repositories{}}, per some other post, and got 32 warnings. Going back to this simple set of statements cleaned them up. I wish that Gradle would provide information about how it operates so that it was obvious why each error or warning is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the some problem, try to change
compileSdkVersion 26  to         compileSdkVersion 28

and then come back again to 26 if required