# ERROR: Failed to resolve: sqlite Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to sync a Kotlin project from GitHub in Android Studio. During the build process first I get the following warning:

> "Warning:***project ':app': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration** Details: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugImplementationDependenciesMetadata'. Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find sqlite.jar (androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1). Searched in the following locations: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/sqlite/sqlite/2.0.1/sqlite-2.0.1.jar*"

Then I get the following error:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: sqlite
>   Affected Modules: app

when I try to rebuild it by clicking make project, I get a different error:

> Could not find sqlite.jar (androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/sqlite/sqlite/2.0.1/sqlite-2.0.1.jar

I checked the following question:

> [Gradle sync failed - Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7:26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567904/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-resolve-appcompat-v726)

and added google maven to my root but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check with google repository by adding following in project build.gradle.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code to  build.gradle, but, still the same