# How to fix "ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"

Tags: android, android-studio

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0
        Add Google Maven repository and sync project
        Show in Project Structure dialog
        Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357000/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-0-0)

Comment: May post your build.gradle file.
Meanwhile you can try: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'